# second auto increment in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have a mySQL (InnoDB) table:

```
belegID int NOT_NULL PRIMARY_KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
docNum int NOT_NULL,
docYear date NOT_NULL,
.... -- more columns
```

I need the following relations:

- belegID is the primary key (unique ID).
- docNum is also a (unique) ID but related to the year. Each year starts by 1.

How can I solve this on mySQL side and how can I get the next docNum (ID related to the year)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If each year starts with 1, it's not unique

Comment: If you want to do that in MySQL only, then use triggers. Are you allowed to do that?

Comment: Rowland: that's true. that is the reason why unique is in bracket.
Alma: Thank you for the hint. I hoped there are another solution and yes I'm allowed do to that.
I give you a feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to resolve your issue. Here is simple example (don't forget to rename schema and table if you'll try to use that):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER fillDocNumber BEFORE INSERT ON test.t
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET @maxNum  = (SELECT MAX(docNum) FROM test.t WHERE YEAR(docYear)=YEAR(NEW.docYear));
  IF @maxNum IS NULL THEN
     SET NEW.docNum=1;
  ELSE
     SET NEW.docNum=@maxNum+1;
  END IF;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Let's assume we have table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
  `belegID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `docNum` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `docYear` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`belegID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

After creating our trigger we'll populate it with some data:

```
mysql> insert into t (docYear) values ('2013-04-06');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> insert into t (docYear) values ('2012-02-18');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into t (docYear) values ('2013-12-11');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into t (docYear) values ('2014-10-30');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> insert into t (docYear) values ('2014-01-03');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
```

and now it's our result:

```
mysql> select * from t;
+---------+--------+------------+
| belegID | docNum | docYear    |
+---------+--------+------------+
|       1 |      1 | 2013-04-06 |
|       2 |      1 | 2012-02-18 |
|       3 |      2 | 2013-12-11 |
|       4 |      1 | 2014-10-30 |
|       5 |      2 | 2014-01-03 |
+---------+--------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Quite as expected.

*Hint*: rename field `docYear`, it's confusing. Correct name would be `docDate` (or store year in it and document's date in separate field - in fact, that will increase performance since then you'll be able to create index by it and get rid of `YEAR()` function in calculating `MAX` within trigger - and so index will be used).